# Implement AWS Appsync into an Angular application without Amplify

Tags: angular, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I am trying to implement AWS Appsync into our Angular application. Is it required to use AWS Amplify to achieve this? All the documentation and examples that I've seen uses Amplify. It seems like it's not as simple as installing a library and using it's API.

Use case: We want to detect a change from the client, and then take action. Conversely, we also want to be able to publish a change.

Any samples that do NOT use Amplify would be appreciated

Comment: I haven't done it without amplify before, so I can't give a detailed description. But AppSync has been around longer than amplify so it should work without amplify. I think you can use apollo client to connect to the graphQl api that AppSync is creating. https://www.apollographql.com/client/

Comment: Yes, you should be able to use the apollo client to connect to AppSync.

Comment: It is possible to connect to Appsync with Apollo but GraphQL subscriptions will not work